# Angular / TypeScript, when using multiple components, 1st component affect 2nd component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a library [Angular-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid) which is a wrapper of a `jQuery` data grid library and is Open Source. It all work nicely when there's only 1 grid (component) on the page but when I want to create 2 of these components (same selector) on the same page, I start to get lot of weird behaviors. The behavior I can see is that some of 1st functions affects the 2nd grid. I can deal with the Services singleton, but in my case it's really the properties of the component that get override by the last created component, why is that? I thought each Angular components were totally independent (apart from the Services), so what am I doing wrong?

I use `ng-packagr` to create my lib and the `ngModule` of the component is the following

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AngularSlickgridComponent,
    SlickPaginationComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    AngularSlickgridComponent,
    SlickPaginationComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [AngularSlickgridComponent]
})
export class AngularSlickgridModule {
  static forRoot(config: GridOption = {}) {
    return {
      ngModule: AngularSlickgridModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: 'config', useValue: config},
        CollectionService,
        ControlAndPluginService,
        ExportService,
        FilterService,
        GraphqlService,
        GridEventService,
        GridExtraService,
        GridOdataService,
        GridStateService,
        GroupingAndColspanService,
        OdataService,
        ResizerService,
        SharedService,
        SortService
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

The component class starts with

```
@Injectable()
@Component({
  selector: 'angular-slickgrid',
  templateUrl: './angular-slickgrid.component.html',
  providers: [ResizerService]
})
export class AngularSlickgridComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {
```

Then in my App, I call the external grid module like this

```
imports: [
  AppRoutingRoutingModule,
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  }),
  AngularSlickgridModule.forRoot({
    // add any Global Grid Options/Config you might wantApp
    enableAutoResize: true
  })
],
```

Then I can create 2 grids in my View like this

```
    <angular-slickgrid gridId="grid1"
          [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
          [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
          gridHeight="200"
        gridWidth="800"
          [dataset]="dataset">
</angular-slickgrid>

<hr>

<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid2"
          [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions2"
          [gridOptions]="gridOptions2"
          gridHeight="200"
        gridWidth="800"
          [dataset]="dataset2">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

After spending a lot of time debugging, I did find out that the 1st component completely override the properties of the 2nd component. If I destroy the 2nd component, it doesn't fix the issue. For example, I click on a column to sort it on both grid, when I click on "clearSort()" from the 1st grid, it actually clears the sort of the 2nd grid!? I also found that properties of only the last created grid remains, if I click on "clearSort()" from 1st or 2nd grid, it will clear it in the 2nd always.

I know how to deal with Services Singleton, but my issue is really the properties of the class that are somehow shared by the 2 components... or to put it in another perspective, 1st component class properties get overridden by 2nd component properties

Is there something that I'm missing to make these 2 components completely independent? I have been searching and trying for couple of hours already, is that even possible or is that normal behavior?

**EDIT**

If you want to see all the code, everything is available from GitHub, you can see the 2 grids code (which is currently on a separate branch):

- [View](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/feature/multiple-grids-same-view/src/app/examples/grid-rowselection.component.html)
- [Component](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/feature/multiple-grids-same-view/src/app/examples/grid-rowselection.component.ts)
- [App Module](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/feature/multiple-grids-same-view/src/app/app.module.ts)
- [Library Component](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/feature/multiple-grids-same-view/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/components/angular-slickgrid.component.ts)
- [Library Module](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/feature/multiple-grids-same-view/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/modules/angular-slickgrid.module.ts)

**EDIT 2**
After all these hours, I found out that it **was** related to Services Singleton. Answered my own question down below. Hopefully this will help someone else facing similar issues.

See below for the behavior, watch the data but also the blue sort icons, it all happens on the 2nd grid while I do the action on 1st grid

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I found the issue and I did not expect what I found to be the issue... My library had no `providers` in it, and so all Services were acting as Singleton. Because of that, any Services function call were using the internal variables (`grid`, `gridOptions`, `dataView`) of the last created grid. So the only thing that I had to do, in order to fix this, was to provide all Services into the `providers` array.

**BEFORE**

```
@Injectable()
@Component({
  selector: 'angular-slickgrid',
  templateUrl: './angular-slickgrid.component.html',
  providers: [ResizerService]
})
```

export class AngularSlickgridComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {

**AFTER**

```
@Injectable()
@Component({
  selector: 'angular-slickgrid',
  templateUrl: './angular-slickgrid.component.html',
  providers: [
    ControlAndPluginService,
    ExportService,
    FilterService,
    GraphqlService,
    GridEventService,
    GridExtraService,
    GridStateService,
    GroupingAndColspanService,
    ResizerService,
    SortService
  ]
})
export class AngularSlickgridComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {
```

Oh my... so many hours wasted for such simple thing

Answer (score 0):

Both component instances, even of the same component class, should have their own scope. Their variables are encapsulated and unique if they aren't declared as static.

Are you sure that dataset and dataset2 do not share the same reference? Avoid following, even for tests:

```
private dataset = [data1, data2];
private dataset2 = dataset;
```

That would enforce the described weired behaviour if you input dataset and dataset2 to two different components.

You are wrapping a jquery plugin which itself is plain javascript. Maybe the wrapped javascript is revoking angulars component scoping?

Are you sure that component instances do not share data by services mistakenly?

Comment: I updated my question to provide links for all the necessary code. The problem is not really with the dataset, it's the `grid`, `gridOptions` & `dataView` objects that all seem to be shared (overridden) and I don't understand why. Nothing seems to be shared from the App with 2 grids. The clear sort from 1st grid happening on 2nd grid, is not just dataset wize, but also sort icon & data that goes away in 2nd grid instead of 1st grid